# Compiling error in Visual Studio 2017 for a Sapera demo

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

When I try to compile the project in Visual Studio 2017 it returns this error, the project is made in C++.

[image: Compiling error]

[image: This is the project code]

Comment: Can you [edit] this question to include the text (not a picture) of the English-language error you are getting?  A question that is mostly pictures is not appropriate here for many reasons.

Comment: This is not a compile error. It looks like you are trying to execute a dll project.

Comment: Set `GigEBayerDemo` as the startup project from its contextual menu.

Answer (score 0):

Under the current solution, there are multiple projects, including projects that generate dll files. The project that directly starts debugging does not correspond to the project that needs to be debugged: Right-click the project that needs to be debugged, such as `GigEBayerDemo` -> Set as StartUp Project